I am not able to control the brightcove videos with amp-story controls
I am writing to inform you about an issue I have encountered with video controls in our current implementation. Specifically, I am able to control the video functionalities such as play/pause and mute/unmute for videos embedded within the amp-video tag. However, I am facing difficulties in achieving the same level of control for videos embedded within the amp-brightcove tag.
Despite following the standard procedures and guidelines for both tags, the amp-brightcove tag does not seem to respond to the play/pause and mute/unmute commands as expected. This inconsistency is affecting the user experience and requires further investigation to identify the root cause and implement a solution.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have to resolve this issue. Your expertise in this matter would be highly valuable.
Thank you for your attention to this matter. I look forward to your response.


<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-story" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-1.0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-brightcove-0.1.js"></script>

<style amp-custom>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    amp-story * {
      font-family: 'Helvitica Nueve', sans-serif;
      color: white;
    }
    amp-story-page {
      background: white;
    }
    amp-story h1 {
      font-size: 46px;
    }
    amp-story h2 {
      font-size: 36px;
    }
    amp-story p {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .bottom {
      align-content: end;
    }
    .medium {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .first {
      padding-top: 65px;
    }
    .last {
      padding-bottom: 65px;
    }
    .blue {
      color: #4285F4;
    }
    .twenty-px {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .lh30 {
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    .icon {
      background-image: url(https://ampbyexample.com/img/AMP-Brand-White-Icon.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 50px 50px;
      height: 50px;
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .byline {
      letter-spacing: 1.28px;
      padding-bottom: 58px;
    }
    .introducing * {
      line-height: 42px;
    }
    .subtitle-page {
      padding-top: 80px;
    }
    .button {
      align-items: center;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      display: flex;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 240px;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
    .button p {
      font-size: 20px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    amp-ad[template="image-template"] img,
    amp-ad[template="video-template"] {
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    ::cue {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
  </style>

<amp-story class="cus_amp_story i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-experiment-story-load-inactive-outside-viewport i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-story-desktop-one-panel i-amphtml-layout i-amphtml-story-loaded" data-theme="drupal" standalone="" publisher="" publisher-logo-src="1X1" poster-portrait-src="2560X2560" i-amphtml-layout="container" muted="" orientation="portrait">
  <amp-story-page class="cus_amp_story_page i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout i-amphtml-story-page-loaded" id="1" auto-advance-after="5.0s" i-amphtml-layout="container" role="region" distance="1" aria-hidden="true" i-amphtml-visited="">
                            <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                    <amp-img layout="responsive" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/613/768/1024.jpg?hmac=LthNoDto5PknucwJyUK1C87uGJtoduIoHKQTH7gHCTI" width="768" height="1024" alt="" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited="" style="--loader-delay-offset: 31ms !important;"><i-amphtml-sizer slot="i-amphtml-svc" style="padding-top: 133.333%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
                        <noscript>
                            <img src="https://example.com/image.png" alt="Example" loading="lazy">
                        </noscript>
                    <img decoding="async" alt="" src="https://lhcdn.mars.com/adaptivemedia/rendition/id_61b3aaa7d2d2e986021361494fb627eaee7c518b/name_61b3aaa7d2d2e986021361494fb627eaee7c518b.jpg" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited=""></amp-img>
                </amp-story-grid-layer>
                                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                    <amp-img class="site_logo i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" width="70" height="40" layout="fixed" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" alt="" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" style="width: 70px; height: 40px;" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited=""><img decoding="async" alt="" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited=""></amp-img>
                </amp-story-grid-layer>
                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="lower-third" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                <div class="lower-third amp_story_content" animate-in="fly-in-bottom" animate-in-delay="0.5s" animate-in-duration="2s">
                    <h2>
                        Story 1
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
            </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Loading video"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-container"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-layer"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper left"></div><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper right"></div></div></div></div></amp-story-page>
  <amp-story-page class="cus_amp_story_page i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout i-amphtml-story-page-loaded" id="2" auto-advance-after="5.0s" i-amphtml-layout="container" role="region" distance="0" aria-hidden="false" active="">
                                                                    <amp-brightcove data-account="906043040001" data-video-id="1401169490001" data-player-id="180a5658-8be8-4f33-8eba-d562ab41b40c" layout="responsive" width="768" height="1024" dock="" controls="" autoplay="" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout i-amphtml-media-component i-amphtml-video-interface" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" data-param-playsinline="true" style="--loader-delay-offset: 0ms !important;"><i-amphtml-sizer slot="i-amphtml-svc" style="padding-top: 133.333%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
                    <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://players.brightcove.net/6269594386001/Nw1A2pmyy_default/index.html?amp=1&amp;videoId=6339975644112&amp;playsinline=true" class="i-amphtml-fill-content"></iframe><i-amphtml-video-icon class="amp-video-eq amp-video-eq-play"><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-1-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-1-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-2-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-2-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-3-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-3-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-4-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-4-2"></div></div></i-amphtml-video-icon><button aria-label="Unmute video" class="i-amphtml-video-mask i-amphtml-fill-content" tabindex="0"></button></amp-brightcove>
                                                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                    <amp-img class="site_logo i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" width="70" height="40" layout="fixed" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" alt="" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited="" style="width: 70px; height: 40px;"><img decoding="async" alt="" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
                </amp-story-grid-layer>
                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="lower-third" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                <div class="lower-third amp_story_content" animate-in="fly-in-bottom" animate-in-delay="0.5s" animate-in-duration="2s" style="transform: translate(0px, 86.018px);">
                    <h2>
                        Story 2
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
            </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Loading video"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-container"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-layer"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper left"></div><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper right"></div></div></div></div></amp-story-page>
  <amp-story-page class="cus_amp_story_page i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout i-amphtml-story-page-loaded" id="3" auto-advance-after="5.0s" i-amphtml-layout="container" role="region" distance="0" aria-hidden="false" active="">
                                                <amp-story-grid-layer template="fill" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                        <amp-video autoplay="" loop="" width="768" height="1024" poster="" layout="responsive" alt="" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-disable-mediasession i-amphtml-poolbound i-amphtml-media-component i-amphtml-video-interface i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="responsive" preload="auto" style="grid-area: middle-third;"><i-amphtml-sizer slot="i-amphtml-svc" style="padding-top: 133.333%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>
                            
                        <video class="i-amphtml-pool-media i-amphtml-pool-video i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" id="i-amphtml-pool-media-4" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" preload="auto" loop="" poster="" muted=""><source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bbb-splash.png" type="video/mp4"></video><i-amphtml-video-icon class="amp-video-eq"><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-1-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-1-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-2-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-2-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-3-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-3-2"></div></div><div class="amp-video-eq-col"><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-4-1"></div><div class="amp-video-eq-filler amp-video-eq-4-2"></div></div></i-amphtml-video-icon></amp-video>
                    </amp-story-grid-layer>
                                                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                    <amp-img class="site_logo i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" width="70" height="40" layout="fixed" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" alt="" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" i-amphtml-auto-lightbox-visited="" style="width: 70px; height: 40px;"><img decoding="async" alt="" src="http://mars.ddev.site:8080/sites/default/files/logo_buckeye.png" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content"></amp-img>
                </amp-story-grid-layer>
                        <amp-story-grid-layer template="lower-third" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-container i-amphtml-story-layer i-amphtml-built i-amphtml-layout" i-amphtml-layout="container">
                <div class="lower-third amp_story_content" animate-in="fly-in-bottom" animate-in-delay="0.5s" animate-in-duration="2s" style="transform: translate(0px, 86.018px);">
                    <h2>
                        Story 3
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
            </amp-story-grid-layer>
        <div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Loading video"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-container"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-layer"><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper left"></div><div class="i-amphtml-story-spinner-circle-clipper right"></div></div></div></div></amp-story-page>
 </amp-story>



